# Handsontable Incorrect Column Height Sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

I have the following handsontable loaded into a html div.

HTML

```
<div id="example1"></div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.handsontable .colHeader {
   overflow: hidden;
   /* Expands or shrinks column names as required to fill the available free
   space. Stops column headers overflowing onto filters. Causings Col Header row 
   sizing issues on IE and Edge when enabled. */
   display: flex;
   height: 20px;
}
</style>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

var container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 200)
    , rowHeaders: true
    , rowHeaderWidth: 25
    , rowHeights: 25
    , colHeaders: true
    , colWidths: 40
    , columnSorting: true
    , filters: true
    , dropdownMenu: true
  });  

});
```

You can view it in operation in the following link.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/nbLy6j04/

I want my column header names to be hidden behind the column filter symbol. So I have changed the  display property of the ColHeaders to flex. Which works fine on all browsers.

However, changing this display value causes strange behaviour on MS Edge and IE. Specifically it causes the Column Heights to be re-sized incorrectly on scrolling of the table. See image below.

[image: col-heights-bug]

Which is explainable by the fact IE and Edge do not properly support display: flex.

So my question is. Is there any changes I can make to my code to achieve the functionality I want. I.e. if the column header text overflows the column (and filter button) hide the overflowing section of the text?